# Can I migrate Sharepoint 2010 databases from a SQL 2008R2 server to SQL 2012 server?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, migration, sql-server-2012

I'd like to migrate my SharePoint 2010 Foundation databases from a SQL 2008 R2 server (running on Windows Server 2008 R2) to a server running SQL 2012 (on a Windows Server 2012 box), and would like to know if it is possible, and if there are any huge gotchas or red flags I should be aware of.

I've found some information that suggest it's possible, but a Technet piece that I recently read suggests that in order for the migration to be successful, the target server needs to be the same OS and version of SQL (though I've been burned by putting too much faith in Technet before).

Assuming it's possible, here's the 30K ft view of my plan:

- Stop Sharepoint Services and IIS on my WFEs
- Detach the Sharepoint DBs from SQL SERVER A
- Move all the associated *df files from SQL SERVER A to SQL SERVER B
- Configure security on SERVER B identical to SERVER A
- Attach the DBs on SERVER B
- Verify ports and create aliases on SERVER B
- Fire up all the Sharepoint Services and IIS again

Again, just trying to get clarity on my plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recently moved the Config / Content Database from Sql 2008 R2 to Sql Server 2012 with out issue.

If you are only moving the content database then its easy. I am sure you used the SQL alias then it is super easy.

I would recorded you to test at least one database and make sure the things goes well.

Our Method is almost same just little change For Config DBs.

- Completely shut down the SharePoint.
- Detach the DB from SharePoint and Move the DBs to new server( keeping the source file on the source server for in case of things not goes well).
- Once DB moved and permission and other settings applied.
- Update the DNS Alias.
- Restart the SharePoint.

For Content Database. Instead of Shutting down sharepoint, we simply detach the content database from SharePoint. and after move, reattach it using the new SQL server.

Possible issues are

- Permission mising
- DB setting( autogrowth)
- In rare case, may need to clear config cache.

Comment: An answer based on experience--exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you very much for the added insight as well.