# Move SharePoint 2007 databases

Tags: sql, server

I have a SQL 2008 server I need to migrate the SharePoint databases to a new SQl 2008r2 server.  Not heavily used, I believe I want to do the following:

1.Shutdown SharePoint
2.backup the databases
3.restore databases and appropriate logins to new server

Then what do I do to point SharePoint to new backend (sorry this question is coming from dba).

Answer (score 0):

Once you moved the database new server after that if you use SQL Alias...

- Refer the farm to the new database server by creating a SQL Server
  connection alias.

If you are using the DNS alias then you just need to update DNS alias.
After that start your SharePoint.

Read the Technet for more details, how to create alias etc

[Move all databases (Office SharePoint Server 2007)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Check my response over here...[Can I migrate Sharepoint 2010 databases from a SQL 2008R2 server to SQL 2012 server?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113451/can-i-migrate-sharepoint-2010-databases-from-a-sql-2008r2-server-to-sql-2012-ser/113452#113452)

Comment: thought that would work, however will the alias cause an issue for existing databases on the server I am moving to?

Comment: what issue with exisitng database server?